# SSRS report to show missing/ NULL entries Mon to Fri.

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression

I have created a report that shows the results of the last entry per day (MAX(Date)), but I now need to show if a date entry wasn't recorded / NULL (Mon-Fri only).

I can get the week day name or INT using an expression.

My problem is how do I show if a value is missing. i.e. Monday, Tuesday, Thursday has entry. Wednesday & Friday no entry recorded.

I have tried doing this in SQL, but got lost with an already over-engineered Stored Proc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is still the best way to get all the data you need.  What I would recommend is creating a temp table with the limited values list you want, for instance Monday, Tuesday, etc.  Then you can use the apply operator against your data table and get the not matching day values.

```
SELECT * FROM Days D 
OUTER APPLY 
   ( 
   SELECT * FROM Orders E 
   WHERE DATEPART(wd,e.OrderDate) = D.DayName
   ) A
```

Would return something like:

```
DayName    OrderCount  Amount
Monday     2           50.00
Tuesday    NULL        NULL
Wednesday  5           125.00
Thursday   NULL        NULL
Friday     7           225.00
```

Below you can find an article on the apply operators that you can use:

[Cross and Outer Apply](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/)

Comment: I used the temp table idea and joined it to my existing procedure. It seems to have very little affect on performance, which is always a bonus. Thanks for your help.